# How do I debug JmsTemplate?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jmstemplate

I am using SpringsourceTool and the Spring framework.

I have some code that uses `JmsTemplate` to send messages via `convertAndSend(Object)`. I want to debug it as a JUnit test. So, for the test class, I select `Run->Debug As->JUnit Test`.

I set a breakpoint and was able to closely follow the trace until I hit `jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(obj)` in which case when I hit `Step Into (F5)`, I get a

```
Source not found.
Edit Source Lookup Path
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your problem is to with how to use Eclipse, and attaching sources to your library dependencies.  This isn't a problem with `JmsTemplate` or Spring.

Having said that, you don't need to unit test `JmsTemplate` - it's already been unit tested by the Spring team. You can assume it works.

If your code is coupled to `JmsTemplate`, then consider refactoring it to depend on the `JmsOperations` interface instead. You can then mock or stub out that interface in your test.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is the problem I am trying to solve:  org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate


Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.

Answer (score 0):

If a deeper introspection into your JMS-communication is needed:

- add `logging.level.com.ibm.mq=TRACE` to your `application.properties`
- add `-Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status=ON` to your java-startup-parameters

Then check

- your application-logfile
- the application-start-directory, where you sould find a `*.TRC`-file with a lot of debug-information

see: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=tmcja-collecting-mq-classes-jms-trace-by-using-java-system-property