# IBM MQ explore with debug

Tags: ibm-mq

Is there a option to do SSL log debugging on the MQ explorer when we connect to Queue manager with SSL enabled?
I have tried with runwithtrace but it doesnt show ssl debugs

Comment: have you tried it in that way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72475148/4994931 ?

Comment: This might help: http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB/viewtopic.php?t=64172&sid=d404a8f51229fa0069947297984d791e

Comment: @gratinierer   I tried adding -Djavax.net.debug=all , but where does the log file create?

Comment: @JoshMC  i tried, but where to find the location of the logs?

Comment: Ssl debug writes to standard out of Java. But not where explorer writes that.

Comment: in my cases I found files like `mqjavaclient_17716.trc` in the directory the application has been started from